# jQuery change form ID and submitting the "new" form

Tags: jquery, forms, attr

I have a form that has the ID "addCat" .. i'm using jquery to change the ID into "editCat" and fill the form inputs with pre-existing data, then submit the new form.

aparantly the new ID is updated but the form is not submitted?

```
$("#addTags").on("submit",function(){
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();;
    $.post("./Scripts/adminDoAddCat.php", dataString, function (data) {
        if (data == "1") {
        $('div.add_result').html("<h3>New Category Added Successfully</h3>").fadeIn(800);
        }
        if (data == "0") {
        alert("Something went wrong");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
$("tbody tr td a.fa-pencil-square").on("click",function(){
    $("form#addTags").attr('id','editTags');
    alert($('form').attr('id')); //this is the way i make sure ID is updated 
});
    $("#editTags").on("submit",function(){
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();;
    alert(dataString); //making form is recognized but it's not working
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()` to change the ID

```
$("form#addTags").prop('id','editTags');
```

Then use [**Event Delegation**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to bind submit handler

```
$(document).on("submit","#editTags",function(){
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();;
    alert(dataString); 
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Still not sensing the form submit event

Comment: @TarekSawah, Did you used event delegation?

Comment: +1 for the delegation but attr() would work too and should be used instead to update the DOM attribute

Comment: yes using `$(document).on("submit","#editTags",function(){});`

Comment: @TarekSawah You are doing something wrong, it works here: http://jsfiddle.net/U2ncv/1

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes now it's working properly I had to use delegation on both forms in the jquery script.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround for it. But it mayn't be what you desired. Anyway look the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/SSDRU/2/). And let me know if it works for you. Not a good approach though.

```
$("tbody tr td a.fa-pencil-square").on("click",function(){
    $("form#addTags").prop('id','editTags');
    //Define the handler inside of the new 
   $("#editTags").on("submit",function(){
    var dataString = $(this).serialize();;
    alert(dataString); //making form is recognized but it's not working
    return false;
   });
});
```